# How can I generate Oracle Database export script Using Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to Generate an export script of entire Oracle Database  using using SQL Developer.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related question, how to do this scriptably i.e. that can be run from command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886450/how-to-generate-entire-ddl-of-an-oracle-schema

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tools-> Database Export?

Comment: So much simpler than my approach.

Answer (score 3):

For backing up the entire database, I'd recommend using expdp/impdp from the command line.
If you only need the objects and not the data, you can use the METADATA_ONLY setting, see

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm

If you really need to generate a SQL script for your complete database and don't want to use a commercial tool like PL/SQL Developer, TOAD etc., you'll probably have to do it yourself - e.g. iterating over all objects and extract their DDL script using dbms_metadata.get_ddl(), something like 


    `foreach user u in all_users

       foreach object o in users_u_objects

         script += dbms_metadata.get_ddl(u, o)`