# How to generate entire DDL of an Oracle schema (scriptable)?

Tags: oracle, schema, ddl

Can anyone tell me how I can generate the DDL for all tables, views, indexes, packages, procedures, functions, triggers, types, sequences, synonyms, grants, etc. inside an Oracle schema? Ideally, I would like to copy the rows too but that is less important.

I want to do this on a scheduled job of some kind and not manually each time, so that rules out using the wizard in SQL Developer.

Ideally, since I will be running this on several schemas that have grants and synonyms to one another, I would like to have a way to do a find/replace in the output so the schema names match whatever the names of my new schemas are going to be.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL Developer can do this via its command-line interface, so it is possible if you want to go that route.

Comment: Simple run :  SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl(object_Type, object_name, owner) FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER = 'OWNER_NAME';

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can spool the schema out to a file via SQL*Plus and dbms_metadata package.  Then replace the schema name with another one via sed.   This works for Oracle 10 and higher.

```
sqlplus<<EOF
set long 100000
set head off
set echo off
set pagesize 0
set verify off
set feedback off
spool schema.out

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name, owner)
from
(
    --Convert DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_TYPE to DBMS_METADATA object type:
    select
        owner,
        --Java object names may need to be converted with DBMS_JAVA.LONGNAME.
        --That code is not included since many database don't have Java installed.
        object_name,
        decode(object_type,
            'DATABASE LINK',           'DB_LINK',
            'JOB',                     'PROCOBJ',
            'RULE SET',                'PROCOBJ',
            'RULE',                    'PROCOBJ',
            'EVALUATION CONTEXT',      'PROCOBJ',
            'CREDENTIAL',              'PROCOBJ',
            'CHAIN',                   'PROCOBJ',
            'PROGRAM',                 'PROCOBJ',
            'SQL TRANSLATION PROFILE', 'PROCOBJ',
            'REWRITE EQUIVALENCE',     'PROCOBJ',
            'PACKAGE',                 'PACKAGE_SPEC',
            'PACKAGE BODY',            'PACKAGE_BODY',
            'TYPE',                    'TYPE_SPEC',
            'TYPE BODY',               'TYPE_BODY',
            'MATERIALIZED VIEW',       'MATERIALIZED_VIEW',
            'QUEUE',                   'AQ_QUEUE',
            'JAVA CLASS',              'JAVA_CLASS',
            'JAVA TYPE',               'JAVA_TYPE',
            'JAVA SOURCE',             'JAVA_SOURCE',
            'JAVA RESOURCE',           'JAVA_RESOURCE',
            'XML SCHEMA',              'XMLSCHEMA',
            object_type
        ) object_type
    from dba_objects 
    where owner in ('OWNER1')
        --These objects are included with other object types.
        and object_type not in ('INDEX PARTITION','INDEX SUBPARTITION',
           'LOB','LOB PARTITION','TABLE PARTITION','TABLE SUBPARTITION')
        --Ignore system-generated types that support collection processing.
        and not (object_type = 'TYPE' and object_name like 'SYS_PLSQL_%')
        --Exclude nested tables, their DDL is part of their parent table.
        and (owner, object_name) not in (select owner, table_name from dba_nested_tables)
        --Exclude overflow segments, their DDL is part of their parent table.
        and (owner, object_name) not in (select owner, table_name from dba_tables where iot_type = 'IOT_OVERFLOW')
)
order by owner, object_type, object_name;

spool off
quit
EOF

cat schema.out|sed 's/OWNER1/MYOWNER/g'>schema.out.change.sql
```

Put everything in a script and run it via cron (scheduler).  Exporting objects can be tricky when advanced features are used.  Don't be surprised if you need to add some more exceptions to the above code.

Comment: Everything gets wrapped at something like 80 characters even though I have linesize set to 32767. Any way to fix that?

Comment: i want to replicate a DB from one server to other server , so this helps , but i need to arrange the DB objects in sequence -  manually it is not possible to do so as i have 1600 DB objects -  is there a way can we get all the DB objects scripts in sequence - in which they were created for one specific user/schema

Comment: @eisberg GRANT statements can be fetched with the following command:

`select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT', '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>') from dual;`

Comment: This is very nice!!! Thank you. I do have a question though, what needs to change in order to be able to them import it?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to individually generate ddl for each object,

Queries are:

**--GENERATE DDL FOR ALL USER OBJECTS**

**--1. FOR ALL TABLES**

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', TABLE_NAME) FROM USER_TABLES;
```

**--2. FOR ALL INDEXES**

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', INDEX_NAME) FROM USER_INDEXES WHERE INDEX_TYPE ='NORMAL';
```

**--3. FOR ALL VIEWS**

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW', VIEW_NAME) FROM USER_VIEWS;
```

OR

```
SELECT TEXT FROM USER_VIEWS
```

**--4. FOR ALL MATERILIZED VIEWS**

```
SELECT QUERY FROM USER_MVIEWS
```

**--5. FOR ALL FUNCTION**

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('FUNCTION', OBJECT_NAME) FROM USER_PROCEDURES WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
```

===============================================================================================

**GET_DDL** Function doesnt support for some object_type like LOB,MATERIALIZED VIEW, TABLE PARTITION

SO, Consolidated query for generating DDL will be:

```
SELECT OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME,DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME, OWNER)
  FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
  WHERE (OWNER = 'XYZ') AND OBJECT_TYPE NOT IN('LOB','MATERIALIZED VIEW', 'TABLE PARTITION') ORDER BY OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME;
```

Comment: select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('MATERIALIZED_VIEW', 'MVIEW_NAME') from dual; works

Comment: i want to replicate a DB from one server to other server , so this helps , but i need to arrange the DB objects in sequence -  manually it is not possible to do so as i have 1600 DB objects -  is there a way can we get all the DB objects scripts in sequence - in which they were created for one specific user/schema

Comment: @gurupreet-singh-bhatia, does this assume `OWNER = 'XYZ'` is to be replaced with a valid owner? If so, where is this defined? Is it the user?

Answer (score 7):

The get_ddl procedure for a PACKAGE will return both spec AND body, so it will be better to change the query on the all_objects so the package bodies are not returned on the select.

So far I changed the query to this:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(REPLACE(object_type, ' ', '_'), object_name, owner)
FROM all_OBJECTS
WHERE (OWNER = 'OWNER1')
and object_type not like '%PARTITION'
and object_type not like '%BODY'
order by object_type, object_name;
```

Although other changes might be needed depending on the object types you are getting...

Answer (score 6):

First export the schema metadata:

```
expdp dumpfile=filename logfile=logname directory=dir_name schemas=schema_name
```

and then import by using the `sqlfile` option (it will not import data it will just write the schema DDL to that file)

```
impdp dumpfile=filename logfile=logname directory=dir_name sqlfile=ddl.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem with objects such as PACKAGE_BODY:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl(object_Type, object_name, owner) FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER = 'WEBSERVICE';


ORA-31600 invalid input value PACKAGE BODY parameter OBJECT_TYPE in function GET_DDL
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 4018
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5843
ORA-06512: на  line 1
31600. 00000 -  "invalid input value %s for parameter %s in function %s"
*Cause:    A NULL or invalid value was supplied for the parameter.
*Action:   Correct the input value and try the call again.



SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(REPLACE(object_type,' ','_'), object_name, owner)
  FROM all_OBJECTS 
  WHERE (OWNER = 'OWNER1');
```

Comment: It sounds like you are on to something, but it may help to expand on the "trouble" with PACKAGE_BODY and put the SQL code in a tidy little code block.

Comment: You need to replace the spaces for underlines. Try to run: "SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl(replace(object_Type, ' ', '_'), object_name, owner) FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER = 'WEBSERVICE';"

Comment: my post was exactly about it

Answer (score 2):

To generate the DDL script for an entire **SCHEMA** i.e. a **USER**, you could use **dbms_metadata.get_ddl**.

Execute the following script in **SQL*Plus** created by [Tim Hall](https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=script_creation&file=user_ddl.sql):

Provide the **username** when prompted.

```
set long 20000 longchunksize 20000 pagesize 0 linesize 1000 feedback off verify off trimspool on
column ddl format a1000

begin
   dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
   dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
end;
/

variable v_username VARCHAR2(30);

exec:v_username := upper('&1');

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', u.username) AS ddl
from   dba_users u
where  u.username = :v_username
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('TABLESPACE_QUOTA', tq.username) AS ddl
from   dba_ts_quotas tq
where  tq.username = :v_username
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('ROLE_GRANT', rp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_role_privs rp
where  rp.grantee = :v_username
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('SYSTEM_GRANT', sp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_sys_privs sp
where  sp.grantee = :v_username
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT', tp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_tab_privs tp
where  tp.grantee = :v_username
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('DEFAULT_ROLE', rp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_role_privs rp
where  rp.grantee = :v_username
and    rp.default_role = 'YES'
and    rownum = 1
union all
select to_clob('/* Start profile creation script in case they are missing') AS ddl
from   dba_users u
where  u.username = :v_username
and    u.profile <> 'DEFAULT'
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROFILE', u.profile) AS ddl
from   dba_users u
where  u.username = :v_username
and    u.profile <> 'DEFAULT'
union all
select to_clob('End profile creation script */') AS ddl
from   dba_users u
where  u.username = :v_username
and    u.profile <> 'DEFAULT'
and    rownum = 1
/

set linesize 80 pagesize 14 feedback on trimspool on verify on
```

Answer (score -1):

The output of this query is very clean (original [here](https://www.oracle-scripts.net/generate-user-ddl/))

```
clear screen
accept uname prompt 'Enter User Name : '
accept outfile prompt  ' Output filename : '

spool &&outfile..gen

SET LONG 20000 LONGCHUNKSIZE 20000 PAGESIZE 0 LINESIZE 1000 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF TRIMSPOOL ON

BEGIN
   DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
   DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
END;
/

SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER','&&uname') FROM dual;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('SYSTEM_GRANT','&&uname') from dual;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('ROLE_GRANT','&&uname') from dual;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT','&&uname') from dual;

spool off
```

Comment: This script output will only create the user, not the user's objects.