# PLSQL Developer 10.0.2 lost all table reference key when export then import Oracle 11g tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I use PLSQL Developer 10.0.2 (the latest registered version) to export Oracle 11g tables. After I import these tables, I found all the tables lost reference key. I don't want to use SQL Plus.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886450/how-to-generate-entire-ddl-of-an-oracle-schema. Also read more about DBMS_METADATA package on Oracle Docs. That should solve your problem.

Comment: in the `imp`/`exp` there is a parameter called `CONSTRAINTS`. check if when you use plsql developer there is a check box for that. if it still not working - do it manually from the cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is an Pl/Sql Developer internal bug. It has been fixed by Allround Automations company in their latest Pl/Sql Developer 10.0.5.1710.