# How to Export Oracle dump as a SQL script

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I tried to export oracle dump by using the below command

```
exp system/manager@localhost file=file.dmp;
```

I got the output file but the file contains binary format.Which is not readable

I want to export dump as a readable format like sql script

Can any one give me the command for that

Comment: Why don't you want it in a binary format - why is readability important? You should use the tools provided (and look at `expdp` in favour of `exp` now) rather than creating your own mechanism if possible. Do you want just the metadata, or the actual table data as well?

Comment: You can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886450/how-to-generate-entire-ddl-of-an-oracle-schema-scriptable

Comment: My requiremnet is like that only. So, i need readable only not the binary data. If known please tell me the way

Comment: @user3655980 - what tools can you use? SQL Developer has an 'export database' option which will let you export data as insert statements, if that's what you need. If you only need metadata then vkamayiannis has linked to a way to do that, but SQL Developer can do that as well.