# how to remove oracle database 12 and retrieve schema later?

Tags: java, database, oracle, project

I have an Oracle Database 12 and I want to export its design and schema. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please look at How to Ask and how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. This will help to get useful answers.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you ask your teacher/instructor?

Comment: This should give you what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886450/how-to-generate-entire-ddl-of-an-oracle-schema-scriptable