# How import/export package body and spec into .sql or .pkb file

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I need to import/export a package body/spec into a .sql or .pkb file using only sql plus commands.

I tried to execute the standard select but this only display it in the console, but I need the file to modify.

Also I need to do the opposite, that is to import a .sql/.pks/.pkb file to the database in order to apply changes.

Comment: Copy the on-screen output and paste it into a file? Or probably more practically, have you looked at [`spool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/formatting-SQL-Plus-reports.html#GUID-C090CF51-7A15-4372-8504-5EF1232B8DBB)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886450/how-to-generate-entire-ddl-of-an-oracle-schema-scriptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do that using SQL*Plus, then - as you were told - `spool` seems to be a *natural* option. Here's an example, see whether it helps.

First, I'll create a simple package:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test as
  2    function f_today return date;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    function f_today return date is
  3    begin
  4      return sysdate;
  5    end;
  6  end;
  7  /

Package body created.

SQL> select pkg_test.f_today from dual;

F_TODAY
-------------------
02.09.2019 22:28:56

SQL>
```

In order to create a *nice* output file:

- there are some SQL*Plus *settings* that should be set
- as you want to export a package, we'll query `user_source`
- it doesn't contain `create (or replace)` so I'll select it separately
- the same goes for the terminating slash `/`

All that will be stored in a `.SQL` file. If you run those commands directly, the export file will contain `select` statements as well and that's something you'd want to avoid.

`Spool.sql` file:

```
set heading off
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
set termout off
set trimout on
set trimspool on
set recsep off
set linesize 120

spool pkg_test.sql

select 'create or replace' from dual;
select text from user_source
  where name = 'PKG_TEST'
    and type = 'PACKAGE'
order by line;
select '/' from dual;

select 'create or replace' from dual;
select text from user_source
  where name = 'PKG_TEST'
    and type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
order by line;
select '/' from dual;

spool off;
```

Let's run it; because of all those `SET` commands, you won't actually see anything; the `SQL>` prompt will be all, as if nothing happened:

```
SQL> @spool
SQL>
```

But, if you check what's written in `pkg_test.sql` file, you'll see the package:

```
SQL> $type pkg_test.sql
create or replace
package pkg_test as
  function f_today return date;
end;
/
create or replace
package body pkg_test as
  function f_today return date is
  begin
    return sysdate;
  end;
end;
/

SQL>
```

Looks OK, so - to answer your second question (how to *import* it back) - just run it. I'll exit SQL*Plus first; otherwise - again because of `SET` commands - you won't see anything:

```
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

C:\Users\lf>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Pon Ruj 2 22:36:06 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> @pkg_test

Package created.


Package body created.

SQL>
```

Comment: great job. Nice detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For exporting tables
`exp <username>/<password> file=tables.dmp tables=(tab1,tab2)`

For importing tables
`imp <username>/<password> file=tables.dmp tables=(tab1,tab2)`

For printing onscreen output in a file simply use

`spool <filename>` before all your commands to modify your sql outputs as report and spool off after sql commands as

```
 Spool file.txt
 SELECT * FROM TABLE
 SPOOL OFF
```