# Script to create tables from one schema to another

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I want to create tables from one schema to another. i.e. complete table script.
eg: Let say in schema 'A' tables are present and need to create in schema 'B'.
Can we do this with a scripts as there are lot of tables? or manually is the only option?
Could anyone pls suggests.

Thanks.

Comment: you don't need a script. You could use expdp with the CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done by a script. Below, you will find the example of how to retrieve the DLL of a single Table. Now, using this example, you can create the script in no time.

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE', table_name, owner)
FROM   all_tables
WHERE  owner      = 'OWNER'
AND    table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

If you want the script directly, the following Link will provide you with your desired result:

[How to generate entire DDL of an Oracle schema (scriptable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886450/how-to-generate-entire-ddl-of-an-oracle-schema-scriptable)