# How to copy an Oracle DB Schema in Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'd like to copy a schema to a newly created one in Oracle Database, in Oracle Cloud.

As far as I know, these databases are managed ones, so I can't run `expdb` / `impdb` on them.

Any other idea how to copy (~clone) an entire schema?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean something like ATP? You can use data pump (see [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/load-data-data-pump.html#GUID-297FE3E6-A823-4F98-AD50-959ED96E6969)).

Comment: @char yeah, it's an ATP in the Oracle Cloud. But AFAIK the `impdb` runs on the same VM where the database runs.

Comment: 1.Extract DDL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886450/how-to-generate-entire-ddl-of-an-oracle-schema-scriptable. 2.Extract data csv https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/run_export_all_tables.ps1  or insert sql. 3. Create tables  in cloud. 4 Load data into tables(sqlloader or sqlplus). 5Create other objects(indexes, procedures, packages,etc ).6 Recompile functions, procedures, packages, views.

Answer (score 0):

As @dmitry shared above-

`1.Extract DDL stackoverflow.com/questions/10886450/…. 2.Extract data csv github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/… or insert sql. 3. Create tables in cloud. 4 Load data into tables(sqlloader or sqlplus). 5Create other objects(indexes, procedures, packages,etc ).6 Recompile functions, procedures, packages, views.`

Answer (score 0):

Please see @dmitrys response above