# SQL DEVELOPER How to export data with code?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a database called `A2018` and three tables for testing SQL code: ALT, ALT1, ALT2.

So I am running this:

```
SELECT /*insert*/* FROM ALT;
```

This is the output I get:

```
        REM INSERTING into ALT
        SET DEFINE OFF;
        Insert into ALT (ENA,DYO) values ('2','3');
        Insert into ALT (ENA,DYO) values ('1','2');
```

So this only for one table and my question is how to achieve this output with all tables in a single sentence without doing it separate for each table like the output I get when exporting database from Tools.

This is what i am trying to achieve:

```
set echo off
set pagesize 0
set long 90000
SPOOL C:\Export15.sql;


SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name)
    FROM USER_TABLES u;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX',u.index_name)
    FROM USER_INDEXES u;

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('CONSTRAINT',u.constraint_name)
    FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS u;

select /*insert*/* from ALT ;--I WANT IT FOR ALL TABLES IN DATABASE AND NOT ONE BY ONE

SPOOL OFF;
```

Comment: You could script something in SQL*Plus.

Comment: Yes but what happens when tables become more than three?I will have to change the script every time?And if yes isn't there any better way?Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could write a script that creates a script dynamically and executes it in order to handle a changing number of tables. Your question is a little vague though.

Comment: Do you have a link to see how ,so i can adjust it to my needs?

Comment: It's hard to give you much help without a complete question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471429/how-can-i-generate-oracle-database-export-script-using-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: ok i will check.thanks

Comment: it can be done with SQLCL.